# Remapping display line navigation in vim

Tags: vim

I'm currently setting up a `.vimrc` and remapping my home-row (ie navigation keys) to wormkan. So for example I have

```
nnoremap n j
nnoremap j n
```

which works all well and good, but I'm having issues with figuring out how to use display line navigation with this setup.

Basically, if I want to move down one display line on a qwerty layout this would be achieved with `gj` - so now I want this to happen with `gn`.

However, `gn` currently still maps to visual search and `gj` is still associated with the display line navigation. I thought that operator-pending mode would help here (ie adding `onoremap n j` and *vice versa*) but this doesn't have the desired result. Any ideas on what I have to do to get this functioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading:   `:help gn`

> ```
>                               *gn* *v_gn*
> gn        Search forward for the last used search pattern, like
>           with `n`, and
> ```
>
> **start Visual mode to select the match.**
>
> ```
>           If the cursor is on the match, visually selects it.
> ```
>
> **If an operator is pending, operates on the match.**
>
> **E.g., "dgn" deletes the text of the next match.**
>
> ```
>           If Visual mode is active, extends the selection
>           until the end of the next match.
> ```

You realize that `gn` is the **motion command**. That's why mapping `:onoremap n j` did not work as expected. What you need instead is  `:noremap gj gn`.

Comment: Could have sworn I tested this already! Mapping `nnoremap gn gj` and `nnoremap gj gn` has done precisely what I'm looking for. Thanks!